# Alocação dinâmica de vetores

Tags: c, array, gerenciamento-de-memória, alocação

Segue o enunciado:

> Faca um programa que leia numeros do teclado e os armazene em um
>   vetor alocado dinamicamente. O usuario ir digitar uma sequencia de
>   numeros, sem limite de quantidade. Os numeros serao digitados um a um
>   e, sendo que caso ele deseje encerrar a entrada de dados, ele ira
>   digitar o numero ZERO. Os dados devem ser armazenados na memoria deste
>   modo
>
> - Inicie com um vetor de tamanho 10 alocado dinamicamente;
> - Apos, caso o vetor alocado esteja cheio, aloque um novo vetor do tamanho do vetor anterior adicionando espaco  para mais 10 valores
>     (tamanho N+10, onde N iniciacom 10);
> - Copie os valores ja digitados da area inicial para esta area maior e libere a memoria da area inicial;
> - Repita este procedimento de expandir dinamicamente com mais 10 valores o vetor alocado cada vez que o mesmo estiver cheio. Assim o
>     vetor ira ser 'expandido' de 10 em 10 valores.
>
> Ao ﬁnal, exiba o vetor lido. Nao use a funcao REALLOC.

Sou bem novata ainda, então provavelmente, tem muitas coisas erradas no meu código.

Eu tentei usar um segundo vetor, passar tudo para ele, alocar mais 10 espaços no vetor principal e depois passar tudo para ele de novo.

Porém, quando vou digitando eu chego no 19 e o programa pára. Nos 10 primeiros, ele funciona perfeitamente, mas depois quando vou alocar mais 10 (no caso o vetor ficaria com 20 espaços) ele não funciona.

Segue o código que fiz:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(){
    int *vet, c=1, c2=0, *vet1, aux;

    vet =(int*) calloc(10, sizeof(int));

    do {
        scanf("%d", &aux);

        if (c == 10){

            vet1 = (int*) malloc (c2 * sizeof(int));

            for (int i=0; i<c2+1; i++) vet1[i] = vet[i];    

            vet = (int*) malloc (c2 * sizeof(int));

            for (int i=0; i<c2; i++) vet[i] = vet1[i];

            c = 1;
        }

        c++;
        c2++;
        vet[c2] = aux;

    } while (aux != 0);

    printf("\n\n")    ;
    for (int i=0; i<c2; i++) printf("%d  ", vet[i]);

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: E por que não usar `realloc()`? Mais alguma coisa que não pode usar? Eu consigo ver vários problemas no código.

Comment: porque está no enunciado.. só isso mesmo que diz para não usar

Comment: O que é isso: `for (int i=0; i<c2; i++) vet[i] = vet[i];`? Ps: É melhor escrever o enunciado. Não da pra entender muito bem pelo seu código

Comment: ah, essa parte eu tinha arrumado mas não deu pra salvar (queda de energia). agora arrumei ali em cima. é vet[i] = vet1[i] pra passar tudo o que estar no vet1 para o vet

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Um dos motivos da confusão é o código usar nomes de variáveis difíceis de entender o que elas significam. Com nomes melhores pode-se seguir melhor o que está acontecendo. O código faz mais do que deve e cai em algumas armadilhas.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {
    int indice = 0, indiceParcial = 0;
    int *vetor = malloc(sizeof(int) * 10);
    while (1) {
        int valor;
        scanf("%d", &valor);
        if (valor == 0) break;
        vetor[indice++] = valor;
        if (indiceParcial++ == 9) {
            int *vetorAuxiliar = malloc(sizeof(int) * (indice + 10));
            memcpy(vetorAuxiliar, vetor, indice * sizeof(int));
            free(vetor);
            vetor = vetorAuxiliar;
            indiceParcial = 0;
        }
    }
    printf("\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < indice; i++) printf("%d  ", vetor[i]);
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/vm2fxN). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/butssiko-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Array/ManualRealloc.c).

- Só declare a variável quando precisa dela
- Não precisa do `calloc()` e **não deve** fazer *cast* do resultado.
- Não estou me preocupando com o teste para ver se a alocação falou porque em exercício assim não falhará
- Este é um típico laço sem fim já que a saída se dá no miolo dele não tem porque usar condição
- Assim que o valor é digitado deve determinar se continua ou sai do laço
- A primeira coisa que deve operar é a adição do valor no vetor
- Depois analisa se o vetor encheu e deve proceder uma realocação e cópia
- Quando deve recriar você cria baseado no tamanho atual mais 10, conforme o enunciado
- E usar `memcpy()` que é função pronta e confiável para copiar dados. Usa-se o `sizeof` nele pelo mesmo motivo que usa no `malloc()`, essas funções operam com base no `char`, então copia byte por byte, e se tem uma quantidade de elementos de um tipo multibyte é preciso multiplicar por esse número
- Não pode esquecer de liberar a memória do vetor anterior
- E aí adota-se o novo vetor criado como o padrão copiando seu endereço (`vetor` se torna nulo depois do `free()`, se tudo correr bem)
- E zeramos o índice parcial que controla quando quebra o limite. É possível eliminar esta variável e fazer um `indice % 10`, porém é quase certo que será mais lento já que a divisão é com larga margem a operação mais lenta do processador. Ou usa uma coisa ou outra, precisa decidir se quer código mais simples ou mais performance
- Talvez fosse melhor usar um `for` reduzindo escopo de 2 variáveis.

Comment: Que implicaçoes tem na execução do programa ao definirmos a mesma variavel N vezes? Como é o caso do int valor dentro do ciclo, a variavel valor vai estar sempre a ser modificada no local da memoria?

Comment: Ao fazer vetor = vetorAuxiliar; vai ser perder o sitio da memoria do vetorAuxiliar, vai ser impossivel dar free() ficando com memory leaks, correto? Vamos aumentando cada vez mais a memoria inutil do programa

Comment: Nenhuma, declaração é algo que só existe no código, não na execução. Na verdade tem de bom estar só no escopo que é usada. Se as duas variáveis apontam para o mesmo lugar como é impossível liberar a memória? Na verdade o que a resposta de vocês fazem não tem sentido. Copia duas vezes e libera duas vezes a mesma coisa.

Comment: Se a pessoa que negativou puder informar o problema eu tento arrumar.

Comment: Não faz sentido porque é o tipico exercicio de quem começa a aprender gerir memoria, é um teste para saberem se alocam e dao free corretamente. Então o resto das respostas fazem sentido, apenas vai custar no desempenho por ter lá ciclos. Se correr o valgrind certamente que irá acusar esse memory leak.

Comment: Ensinar fazer errado nunca faz sentido! Não tem vazamento algum aí, você precisa estudar mais sobre ponteiros.

Comment: Sim, vou ter de estudar mais sobre ponteiros, apenas bastava um free no final no seu codigo, que não causa grande danos. Mas mesmo assim tenho de o agradecer por me alertar sobre possiveis erros no meu codigo

Comment: No final do código não causa mesmo, o fim da execução libera a memória, eu poderia até colocar, e talvez coloque o alerta que em um código que não encerrasse aí poderia colocar um `free()` final, mas não há vazamento pelo motivo que você falou. O negativo foi só pela falta do `free()` no final que não causa problema algum? Na verdade é só gasto de tempo em fazer o que o sistema operacional terá que fazer de qualquer forma.

Comment: Os meus professores sempre me disseram para dar free no fim, mesmo para mim não fazer sentido pelo motivo que disse. Muito obrigado por o que faz a esta comunidade, tento sempre estar a aprender nesta área .

Comment: E eles estão certos, mas precisa ter contexto, é o que fali na outra pergunta, precisa entender o que acontece e não seguir fórmulas, boas práticas, tem que entender o contexto para aplicar o que precisa, não está errado, mas não é necessário em todo contexto. E obrigado, eu tento manter a ordem e qualidade de tudo o que eu posso, não é fácil e dá trabalho fazer o pouco que consigo. Mude a forma de aprender e evolua livremente, você tem condições para isso, eu falo pra muita gente que eu sei que nem tem, só te falta encontrar o caminho.

Answer (score 0):

Seguindo seu estilo...

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(){
    int *vet, c=0, c2=0, *vet1, aux, N=1;

    vet =(int*) calloc(10, sizeof(int));

    do {

        scanf("%d", &aux);
        if(!aux) break;

        if (c%10 == 0){
            N++;
            vet1 = (int*) malloc (N*10 * sizeof(int));
            for (int i=0; i<(10*(N-1)); i++) vet1[i] = vet[i];    
            free(vet);
            vet = (int*) malloc (N*10 * sizeof(int));
            for (int i=0; i<(10*(N-1)); i++) vet[i] = vet1[i];
            free(vet1);
        }
        c2++;
        vet[c++] = aux;
    } while (aux);

    printf("\n\n");
    for (int i=0; i<c2; i++) printf("%d  ", vet[i]);
    printf("\n");
    free(vet1);
    free(vet);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Voce está criando memory leaks e nao está acrescentando mais 10 de capacidade, mas sim VEZES 10

Comment: Você não entendeu o código então... cresce de 10 em 10 sim.. Vezes 10, porém N = N+1 sempre que c é multiplo de 10. Na primeira é 20, depois 30, 40... e assim vai.

Comment: Sim, tem razão, mas o grave problema é mesmo na gestão de memoria, está a cometer muitos memory leaks, está a dar mallocs sem dar free

Comment: Só faltou o free, vou editar ^^

Comment: ==15332== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible

Comment: Tem outro problema, caso digite 10 numeros o programa para, devido ao seu uso da variavel c